# Can we use DefaultIfEmpty to show a default image?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an album task where I need to show images from a DB. Supposing there is no matching image in the DB, can I use `DefaultIfEmpty` to select a default image?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) already has a suitable overload.

You can't provide a default value to `FirstOrDefault()` but you could always use:

```
// Select the first image, or a default otherwise
var image = query.FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultImage;
```

Or you could write your own overload of `FirstOrDefault` which *does* accept a default, of course. Something like this:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    T defaultValue)
{
    // This will only ever iterate once, of course.
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        return item;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Why can't DefaultIfEmpty used here? Doesn't DefaultIfEmpty already have that overload?

Comment: @nawfal: Looks like it does, actually. But FirstOrDefault doesn't.